# Is that possible to change color of EditText `dots`?

Tags: android

If you have an `EditText` with `android:password` equaled to `true` you see "dots" instead of text. I'm wondering if it possible to change color of these dots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you change the color of the text, the color of the dots will change

`android:textColor="#FF0000"` OR `setTextColor(int)`